# Convert a text type input field in a date type one with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, input

Is there a way to convert a `text` type input field to a `date` type one with jQuery, so it will display to the user a date picker? I can add custom fields to a form created by a Wordpress plugin, but it doesn't support `date` nor `datetime-local` field types, and I need a such one.

```
<input name="adverts_eventDate" id="adverts_eventDate" type="text">
```

Comment: What format are you having the user type the date in? (e.g. mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: @nfnneil I don't have any format yet, as my site is in a development stage :).

Comment: So, do you want a input with the type date after the jQuery or do you want to turn the input with the type text into a date object?

Comment: @nfnneil I want to convert a `<input type="text">` field to a `<input type="date">` field before the form is displayed to users.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: You can't change the date format for HTML5 input date tags, so I included a jQuery-UI example.

Comment: @nfnneil I updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily change the type in jQuery:

```js
$("#adverts_eventDate").attr("type","date");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="adverts_eventDate" id="adverts_eventDate" type="text">
```

You **can't change** date format in HTML5 date:

[Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

**Since you can't change your date format in HTML5,** I would recommend jQuery-UI.

Here's an example:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#adverts_eventDate" ).datepicker();
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input name="adverts_eventDate" id="adverts_eventDate" type="text"></p>
```

Comment: instead of 3/4/16 try to use some format that makes immediately clear what's *date* and what's *month*... *year*... ya?!

Comment: Like March 4th, 2016?

Comment: If you use i.e: `28`, or at least `13` for the date, noone will ever make a bug. If you use 4... who knows what that 4 is. There are loooooots of date formats all over the world... you know?!

Comment: Yeah.  Good point.  I'll see what the the OP wants before I update it.  (I did remove the incorrect statement).

Comment: And `Date` is pretty stupid to decipher them all. (That's why we have Moment.js where you can define literally the desired format etc...)

Comment: ...and the way I interpret the question, this is all irrelevant :)

Comment: The expected date format for my country (Moldova) is `day.month.year` or `day-month-year`.

Comment: @nfnneil This example works! Thank you very much! I will test it on my form a little later. Best regards!

Comment: @nfnneil ... I meant that the second solution/example is what I needed. I tested it with my form and now I have a date picker! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> convert a text type input field in a date type

You can use jquery's `attr` to change the type attribute from text to date.

```js
$("#convert").click(function() {
  $("#adverts_eventDate").attr("type", "date")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="adverts_eventDate" id="adverts_eventDate" type="text">
<button id='convert'>to date</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery-ui as follows

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">       </script>
<input name="adverts_eventDate" id="adverts_eventDate" type="text">
```

and then

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#adverts_eventDate" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```